# Private link to beta app on google play

Tags: android, google-play, beta-testing

I am looking for the best way to privatly publish an app in beta version. I've seen the service Google offer for alpha and beta tester, but it requires the users to be in a google+ community.

Is it possible to simply have something like an invisible download page on google store, only accessible througth a link we can distribute? I assume that would be the simplest way.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want a private link you have to put it on your own server. Google Play doesn't give this option.

the G+ community is what gives you control over it, in G+ you can set a community to private or public, you can accept or not users to join it, you can ban users, and after the user join the community and the testing program the update process is automatic via Google Play.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need to use Google Play for the beta, you could just distribute the APK to the users directly via email. They can just install it from the attachment.